# Change the color of menu icon

Tags: menu, icons

I want the color of the bars in the menu icon to change on mouse hover. So far I'm only able to change the background color. Any suggestions?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Walter69/nwczmdah/5/

```
.container {
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}

.container:hover {
color: #fff!important;
background: #FF0000;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
width: 35px;
height: 5px;
background-color: #000;
margin: 6px 0;
transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change .bar1 {
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .bar2 {
opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .bar3 {
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the color when hover the container:

```
.container:hover .bar1, .container:hover .bar2, .container:hover .bar3 {
    background: #FFF;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nwczmdah/6/